# People Picker. I cannot receive FBA users in Admin Center Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity, fba

My database **membership3** at **.\sharepoint** has many membership users.

There is **web.config** file for my Admin Center Site

```
<configuration>

<connectionStrings>
   <add connectionString="Server=.\sharepoint;Database=membership3;Integrated Security=true" name="SQLAuthConnectionString" />
</connectionStrings>

<SharePoint>
   <PeoplePickerWildcards>
      <clear />
      <add key="SQLAuthConnectionString" value="%" />
      <add key="SQLMembershipProvider" value="%" />
      <add key="SQLRoleManager" value="%" />
  </PeoplePickerWildcards>
</SharePoint>

<system.web>
   <roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
       <providers>
          <add name="SQLRoleManager" connectionStringName="SQLAuthConnectionString" applicationName="/" description="My Role Provider" 
               type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
       </providers>
   </roleManager>
   <membership defaultProvider="SQLMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
      <add name="SQLMembershipProvider" 
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
           connectionStringName="SQLAuthConnectionString" passwordAttemptWindow="5" applicationName="/" enablePasswordReset="true" 
           enablePasswordRetrieval="false" passwordFormat="Clear" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" />
    </providers>
 </membership>
</system.web>

</configuration>
```

There is **web.config** file for my new claims-based site:

```
<configuration>

 <SharePoint>
    <PeoplePickerWildcards>
       <clear />
       <add key="SQLAuthConnectionString" value="%" />
       <add key="SQLMembershipProvider" value="%" />
       <add key="SQLRoleManager" value="%" />
    </PeoplePickerWildcards>
 </SharePoint>

 <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="i">
       <providers>
          <add name="i" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          <add name="SQLMembershipProvider" 
               type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
               connectionStringName="SQLAuthConnectionString" passwordAttemptWindow="5" applicationName="/" enablePasswordReset="true" 
               enablePasswordRetrieval="false" passwordFormat="Clear" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" />
       </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="c" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
       <providers>
          <add name="c" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          <add name="SQLRoleManager" 
            connectionStringName="SQLAuthConnectionString" applicationName="/" description="My Role Provider" 
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
       </providers>
    </roleManager>
 </system.web>

</configuration>
```

File C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\WebServices\Root\web.config :

```
<configuration>

 <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="i">
       <providers>
          <clear />
             <add name="i" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
              <add name="SQLMembershipProvider" 
                   type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
                   connectionStringName="SQLAuthConnectionString" passwordAttemptWindow="5" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
                   requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Clear" />
       </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="c">
       <providers>
          <clear />
          <add name="c" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          <add name="SQLRoleManager" connectionStringName="SQLAuthConnectionString" applicationName="/" description="My Role Provider" 
               type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
       </providers>
    </roleManager>
 </system.web>

    <connectionStrings>
       <add connectionString="Server=.\sharepoint;Database=membership3;Integrated Security=true" name="SQLAuthConnectionString" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I want setting up **User Policy** in Admin Center Site and FBA users are **not coming in People Picker**. But my claims-based authentication site login aesy with any FBA user. What is wrong in Admin Center Site settings?

Comment: have you finally managed to solve the problem ?

Comment: This problem is not solved for me

Comment: our case was a typo in the connection string. so, double check all the settings, or just copy-paste from the config that works.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<add name="i" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
```

in Mermbership
and

```
<add name="c" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
```

in  Role manager at Central Admin web config file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the exact name of the user in the CA people picker?

Comment: yes. I've tried writing the exact name **user1** and search pattern **user%**. There aren't users